# Passing string to function in correct encoding in Java

Tags: java, livelink

I have a folder called Test with the following folder:

- EY 1 P-¦+¡lohy k da+òov+¢m p-¦izn+ín+¡m 2002 - 2004

Then I have the following code

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    File f = new File( "C:\\Test" );
    File [] children = f.listFiles();

    System.out.println( children[0].getName() );
    System.out.println( System.getProperty("file.encoding") );


    lapi.createObjectEx( 0, 3489025, LAPI_DOCUMENTS.OBJECTTYPE, LAPI_DOCUMENTS.FOLDERSUBTYPE , children[0].getName(), ci, oi );

}
```

I executed the code twice. Once using the Netbeans debugger and another using the jar file from the Windows command line.

Netbeans debug output

```
> EY 1 P-¦+¡lohy k da+òov+¢m p-¦izn+ín+¡m 2002 - 2004
> UTF-8
```

Windows Command Line output

```
> EY 1 P-ª+ílohy k da+‗ov+óm p-ªizn+Ýn+ím 2002 - 2004
> Cp1252
```

The lapi object stands for Livelink API and is used to create a folder in a Livelink Server ( now called Content Server ) which is a product from OpenText.

When executing from Netbeans the folder is created with the appropriate name in the Livelink Server. When executed from the Windows command line the folder name contains lots of question marks. The encoding issues mean that the folder's name does not display properly in the resulting webpage.

Does anyone have any ideas how I might be able to fix this and set the encoding explicitly when passing the string to my lapi function?

Comment: This related question might help: [Setting the default Java character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

Comment: Thank you, will have a read.

Answer (score 2):

Use this VM (Command Line) argument:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: It appears to work but will wait for other answers before marking as correct :-)